# Join two mysql tables and display data order by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two mysql tables tblSharesRegistry, tblSharesAccount. I want to join both tables and show rows order by date. But it show data incorrectly. Any help please.

```
1. tblSharesRegistry
    ID  EMPNumber   NoOfShares  Amount  Deposit    Date 
    1   1111         100         10000     1    2012-07-20      
    2   1234         50           5000     1    2012-08-12      
    3   1001         10           1000     1    2012-09-25      
    4   1001         10           1000     1    2012-10-25      
    5   1001         10           1000     1    2012-11-25
    6   1001         -5           -500     0    2012-11-28      

2. tblSharesAccount
    ID  EMPNumber   Balance Interest    Rate    Date    
    1   1111      10000   1000           10 2012-11-29
    2   1234       5000    500           10 2012-11-29
    3   1001       2500    250           10 2012-11-29
```

And the output should be for the EMPNumber: 1001

```
Date         Description    #Shares   Amount   Interest   Total
2012-09-25   Shares bought     10      1000       -        1000
2012-10-25   Shares bought     10      1000       -        2000
2012-11-25   Shares bought     10      1000       -        3000
2012-11-28   Shares sold       -5      -500       -        2500
2012-01-29   Interest          25      2500      250       2750
```

My current code for join the two tables

```
SELECT tblSharesRegistry.Date, tblSharesRegistry.NoOfShares, tblSharesRegistry.Amount, tblSharesAccount.Interest, tblSharesAccount.Date FROM tblSharesAccount INNER JOIN tblSharesRegistry ON tblSharesAccount.EMPNumber = tblSharesRegistry.EMPNumber WHERE tblSharesRegistry.EMPNumber = '1001' ORDER  BY Date DESC
```

**VB.NET Error:**
[image]

Comment: Do you want that query returns the output which you had added in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT sr.Date, IF(sr.NoOfShares > 0, 'Shares bought', 'Shares sold') Description, 
         sr.NoOfShares, sr.Amount, '-' Interest, sr.Amount Total 
FROM tblSharesRegistry sr WHERE sr.EMPNumber = '1001' 
UNION 
SELECT sa.Date, 'Interest' Description, (SELECT SUM(sr.NoOfShares) FROM tblSharesRegistry sr  WHERE sa.EMPNumber = se.EMPNumber) NoOfShares, 
         sa.Balance, sa.Interest, (sa.Balance + sa.Interest) Total 
FROM tblSharesAccount sa WHERE sa.EMPNumber = '1001' ) AS A 
ORDER BY A.date
```

Check this link for better idea on if else statement [**MySQL IF ELSE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)

Comment: It worked perfectly. BTW how can I use if, else in a sql statement and multiple select queries. Any good website for learning? Thanks again for you kind help.

Comment: As you chack my query i had already use if else in my query. Check this statement **IF(sr.NoOfShares > 0, 'Shares bought', 'Shares sold')**. In this statement first argument is my condition, 2nd argument is true and 3rd argument is else part

Comment: This sql statement works perfectly in phpmyadmin and in php code. But when I used same in VB.NET 2010 it shows a error. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I found it. It is a typo. I just copied and pasted the code from the php file. In VB.NET it has added () automatically to that code. I removed it and now its working. Thanks a lot Saharsh for your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT 
tblSharesRegistry.Date, 
tblSharesRegistry.NoOfShares, 
tblSharesRegistry.Amount, 
tblSharesAccount.Interest, 
tblSharesAccount.Date 

FROM tblSharesAccount 
INNER JOIN tblSharesRegistry ON tblSharesAccount.EMPNumber = tblSharesRegistry.EMPNumber 
WHERE tblSharesRegistry.EMPNumber = '1001' ORDER  BY tblSharesRegistry.Date DESC
```